# RabbitMQ - Queue does not get any messages after being idle for long time [ver 3.8.9]

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp

When publishing a new message, the existing queues does not get any messages after being idle for long time.

The producers publish message to the exchange successfully, but no traffic is seen on the bound queue. The producer is a Spring Boot application, where the exchange and queues are created dynamically in runtime using following code snippet.

Creating topic exchange with durable as true and autoDelete as false.

```
TopicExchange exchange = new TopicExchange(topicExchangeName, true, false); 
rabbitAdmin.declareExchange(exchange); 

Queue queue = QueueBuilder.durable(queueName).build(); 
rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue); 

Binding binding = BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(routingKey);
rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(binding);
```

Initially it works fine when the queue is created for the first time.
Once the application is idle for a few days, no new messages appear on the same queue.

Did not observe any connectivity errors. Consumers are still registered.

After deleting the exchange and running the application again, it starts working fine.

**Version:**

Spring Boot - 2.3.4.RELEASE

RabbitMQ - 3.8.9

Spring AMQP - 2.2.7.RELEASE

Note: When creating the queues during application startup instead of dynamically creating the queues, do not see this issue.

Tested with another application with Spring Boot version 2.7.3